# Implementation of static data member at c++

Tags: c++, static-data

I'm working on multi-threading function which defined as a member function and using a common variable of the object.

I'm thinking about **two** approaches :

**1. global variable**

```
static int var = 0;
 class Object {
   void specialOp { var++; }
}
```

**2. static data member**

```
class Object {
   static int var = 0;
   void specialOp { var++; }
}
```

I prefer the second option but when I looked on the internet I didn't find the implementation of **static data member** to know if I need to care of locks or if the complexity is higher than using in a global variable.

Comment: Is the first version in the header file? That behaves completely different, every cpp file, which includes the .h file gets it's own independent version of `static int var = 0;`

Comment: @mch The 2 options are defined in the CPP file

Comment: So what is your question here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `static` keyword in C++ means different things depending on where it is used.

1. In global scope, it defines a global variable without linkage (makes the variable inaccessible outside the current compilation unit of source and included header files)
2. As a class member, it declares a global variable that can be accessed in any files using `Class::variable` but in accordance to the access specifiers of the class (need to declare it in a cpp file as well)
3. In a function, declares a global variable that is only accessible inside the function. Different calls to the same function are guaranteed to access the same memory.

None of the able addresses multithreading though. To address multi-threading, you have a few options:

1. declare the variable `thread_local`. This means each thread gets its own version of the variable.
2. protect multiple access either by using `std::atomic` or some other thread synchronization primitive like a `std::mutex`